# Find a monotone function $u(x)$ such that a random variable has a uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, statistical-inference

> Suppose $X$ has density (pdf) $f_X(x) = \frac{2}{3}(x-1)$ for $2 < x < 3$.
>
> a.) Find the pdf of $Y = -\log X$. (Make sure to specify the range and validity of your answer).
>
> b.) Find a montone function $u(x)$ such that the random variable $Z = u(x)$ has a Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution.

Solution a.) We have from Casella and Berger theorem 2.1.8 $$f_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_X(g^{-1}_i(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}g_i^{-1}(y)\right|$$
We are given $$Y = -\log X \Rightarrow g^{-1}(y) = e^{-y}$$
Thus 
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|\\
&= \frac{2}{3}(e^{-y} - 1)e^{-y}\\
&= \frac{2}{3}e^{-y}(e^{-y} - 1) \ \ \ \ \ \ -\log(3) < y < -\log(2)
\end{align*}
To verify this is correct note that $$\int_{-\log(3)}^{-\log(2)}  \frac{2}{3}e^{-y}(e^{-y} - 1) dy = 1$$

I am not sure how to do part b any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi @wolfy, how did you determine the range for part a?

Comment: @Googme Its just a bit of Algebra note the comment I made "To verify this is corrent note that...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $\Pr(Z\leq z)=z$ if $Z$ is uniformly distributed. Now see that:
$$
\Pr(Z\leq z)=\Pr(u(X)\leq z)=\Pr(X\leq u^{-1}(z))\\
=\int_2^{ u^{-1}(z)}\frac 23(x-1)dx=\frac{u^{-1}(z)^2}{3}-\frac{2u^{-1}(z)}{3}
$$
So we have:
$$
\frac{u^{-1}(z)^2}{3}-\frac{2u^{-1}(z)}{3}=z.
$$
which means that:
$$
u(x)=\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{2x}{3}.
$$

Comment: Just to clarify if I had $$\frac{u^{-1}(z)^2 - 1}{4} + \frac{u^{-1}(z) - 1}{2} = z$$ then would we have $$u(x) = \frac{x^2 - 1}{4} + \frac{x - 1}{2}$$

Comment: Arash can you please answer my question?

Comment: Just take $x=u^{-1}(z)$ which is $z=u (x) $. Then things are more clear.

Comment: ok so then my above inquiry is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes this is correct